# how to cast this data as json in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json, json-extract

I have data in one of my table columns as  like `{x:1,y:2}` . I wanted to cast the data to json like
`{"x":"1","y":"2"}`

I tried to use JSON_QUOTE and cast as JSON with no success.

Comment: Can you add more sample data to your question?

Comment: Because that is not JSON structure.

Comment: all of data is the same.

Comment: @Justinas Why not?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Does it matter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used this Replace section for the answer:

```
REPLACE(CONCAT("{\"",REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(form_field.settings,"\n",","),"=",":") ,",","\",\""),":","\":\""),"\"}"),",\"\"","")
```

then I completed that Like:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(CAST(REPLACE(CONCAT("{\"",REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(form_field.settings,"\n",","),"=",":") ,",","\",\""),":","\":\""),"\"}"),",\"\"","") AS JSON),"$.accessname" )
```